# How resolve canvas game images with phonegap

Tags: javascript, cordova, craftyjs

I just created a basic game using CraftyJS. I create some characters which are referenced to an image. Those images are located in www/img folder. When i run the app on the emulator the images are blank and only texts are showing. How to resolve this?

Comment: So it works ok when you're running it outside of phonegap?  Have you tried [setting the default path](http://craftyjs.com/api/Crafty-paths.html) Crafty looks in for assets?

Comment: Please show code how you loading resources (sprites).